# How to replace multiple empty fields into zeroes using awk

Tags: awk

I am using the following command to replace tab delimited empty fields with zeroes.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" } { for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~ /^ *$/) $i = 0 }; 1'
```

How can I do the same, if I have the following input that is not tab delimited and have multiple empty fields ?

input

```
name              A1348138      A1086070      A1080879      A1070208      A821846       A1068905      A1101931
g1                5       8       1       2       1       3       1
g2                   1       3       2       1       1       2
```

desired output

```
name              A1348138      A1086070      A1080879      A1070208      A821846       A1068905      A1101931
g1                5       8       1       2       1       3       1
g2                   1       3       2       1       1       2       0
```

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: updated@TomFenech

Comment: So the columns are fixed width, rather than tab-separated?

Comment: how do you know whether "s2" or "s3" is missing if it had a different value?

Comment: yes that is correct @TomFenech

Comment: The zeros in the example don't look very "fixed-width" to me!

Comment: yes, it is my bad. I think I solved it myself. Should I delete this question ?sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: A potentially useful thing to do would be fix your input example and post the solution as an answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry, no i think the problem still exists. I updated the input and output.

Comment: I would spend my energy nagging the data producer to give me a tab-delimited version of the data ;-) OR if the missing fields are always on the end of the record, then you can do `awk '{if (NF != 8) printf $0 "   0    0   0\n"}` (Actually, you would need `...!=8) {for (i=NF;i<=12;i++) {printf "    0" ; } printf "\n"} ...` added in there too). Good luck!!

Comment: The data format with the alternating left/right justification, or whatever it is that causes things to be aligned differently, is going to make life hell.  Get the producers to produce a usable format — mutter XML or JSON or CSV to them; anything consistent and formally delimited would be easier than the mess shown.  I have a program written for another system (a long time ago) that translates fixed column ranges to a delimited format — I had to import undelimited fixed-column data from an immovable source into a database that expected (variable-length) delimited format. Ping me if interested.

Comment: thanks @JonathanLeffler.  awk field widths (below answer) trick worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using GNU awk for FIELDWIDTHS  to solve the problem you appear to be asking about and also to convert your fixed-width input to tab-separated output (or something else sensible) while you're at it:

```
$ cat file
1   2   3
4       6

$ gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS='4 4 4' -v OFS='\t' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",$i); $i=($i==""?0:$i)}; print}' file
1   2   3
4   0   6

$ gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS='4 4 4' -v OFS=',' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",$i); $i=($i==""?0:$i)}; print}' file
1,2,3
4,0,6

$ gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS='4 4 4' -v OFS=',' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",$i); $i="\""($i==""?0:$i)"\""}; print}' file
"1","2","3"
"4","0","6"
```

Take your pick of the above.

Comment: Hi the first one is working great but it is not working well when I have row names with variable lengths. @EdMorton. Something like - aaa
bbbb
ccccc
dddddd  ee

Comment: The solution I posted works for fixed width fields, so if you have fixed width fields and the solution isn't working then it's because you are not setting the FIELDWIDTHS variable to the correct widths for each field.. If you do not have fixed width fields then you need to show us what it is you do have and clarify how to identify the fields and I recommend you open a new question in that case and be precise - saying `something like...` is not useful, say `precisely this...` and then show it precisely formatted correctly in your question.